# how to schedule console app in autosys

Tags: scheduler, autosys

I have a console/executable app which I need to configure in autosys which will run every week on Sunday at 12 AM.I have never used autosys. Any help or link will be helpful related with jil command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert_job: JOB_NAME   job_type: c
box_name: BOX_NAME (if you use one)
machine: servername
owner: account /*(which will run the job, must be permissioned on the machine)*/
command: whateveryouwanttorun
condition: s(previousjob) /*(Means run only if previousjob is in succes state)*/
description: "Description Here"
date_conditions: 1 /*(1 or y for yes, 0 or n for no)*/
starts_time: 00:00 /*("00:00" also accepted)*/
days_of_week: su
alarm_if_fail: 1 (1 or y for yes, 0 or n for no)
std_out_file: >>path\filename.log
std_err_file: >>path\errorfile.log

There are lots of other options you can invoke like use of a profile or adding variables or dates to log names etc etc.  For an explanation of any of these you can ask back here or check google or ca.com for the user guide for the version of AutoSys in use at your place (commonly 11.0 or 11.3.n or possibly 4.5).

Good Luck!